# vertical spacing macro

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to make large numbers of slides (=pdf pages)  with one large word on each slide, centered vertically and horizontally.  But the output is not centered vertically.  I tried using the starred version of `vspace` but even that is not helping.  Moreover, there is a first blank page—I have no idea why that has appeared.  What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in] {geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\myslide}[1][]{ \vspace*{\fill} #1  \vspace*{\fill}  \clearpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{Huge}
\begin{centering}

\myslide{rye}
\myslide{raw}
\myslide{red}

\end{centering}
\end{Huge}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a class designed for making slides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the syntax `\newcommand{\myslide}[1][]{...}`, your `\myslide` macro was specified with an optional argument, thus requiring invocation `\myslide[...]` (bracket delimiters, not braces).  I made the argument mandatory, and all was immediately fixed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in] {geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\myslide}[1]{ \vspace*{\fill} #1  \vspace*{\fill}  \clearpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{Huge}
\begin{centering}

\myslide{rye}
\myslide{raw}
\myslide{red}

\end{centering}
\end{Huge}
\end{document}
```